# iOS - Is it possible to send in continuos connection request to a server?

Tags: ios, urlrequest

I have a app code that sends in request only when the app opens. However I need to have a continuos access to the file in the server which will be updated every second.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
    NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myurl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    //myTextView.text = realtime;
    //NSLog(mystring);

    NSString *stripped1 = [mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

    NSArray *rows = [stripped1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

Is there a way that I can keep checking on my server file to load the data? Currently I can load it only once when I open the application. But its a live update application.
Thank you.

Comment: I just have to call that url continously instead of just calling it once when the app opens. Other than using a timer is there a way out?

Comment: Yes, use sockets, they are designed for polling a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use apple notification to notify the user new data.

But I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: The data being generated is later plotted on a graph using core plot. Its more like accessing the server continuously and load the new datas